What determines (commercial) "use" for e-book or online blog?
I've been trying to understand the parameters of what defines "use" of an e-book or a blog. I'm specifically considering the Creative Commons CC-BY-NC license.
Some uses are simple: you can't sell copies of an CC-BY-NC e-book for proft, or copy the contents (violating copyright law).
Some are not so clear:

Can you charge someone for media (CD/DVD) and postal fees for sending then a copy of an e-book? If so, can you charge a reasonable fee for your time (and gas for your car)?

Given that most companies are fundamentally commercial in nature, can you email a link to a CC-BY-NC e-book or blog to your co-workers? Can you email a copy of the e-book or blog (as an attachment)?


So, what constitutes "use"?
(Creative Commons is intentional vague about the definition of "non-commercial", and they are even less helpful regarding the definition of "use".)
